# CSS label element in in form won't display properly

Tags: css

When I click sumbit on the form found here:

http://test-bed.co.uk/garden/book.php

The validation messages don't appear as desired, I would like them to appear alongside the input elements as if they were inline.

I believe the label or input styling rules could be causing the problem. As they are floated the containg div with an id of form is floated left.

```
#aform label {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}

.inputstyle2 {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 240px;
    width: 300px;
}

#form {
    float: left;
}
```

Any suggestions and explanations of what I have done wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: No one is seriously digging into your site´s code.

Comment: I have revised my question accordingly to provide the code which I believe is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to remove `margin-right` and add `clear: both` within `.inputstyle2`:

```
.inputstyle2 {
    clear: both;
    width: 300px;
}
```

The error labels will still be placed underneath the input field as they inherit `clear: both` in `#aForm label` which is removing the float effect. Thankfully you can override this by using a more specific CSS selector and removing the `clear`:

```
#aForm label.error {
    clear: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you My Head Hurts, I seem to be getting closer now.

Comment: @user1554264 no problem - I have realised that the answer I gave you wasn't completely correct, however the revised answer should work

Comment: The final issue is that#aform label appears on the right of the inputs, thanks for your help again. That looks like the final thing to iron out.

Comment: @user1554264 does that occur with my updated answer? *Note, with my updated answer you need to revert* `#aform label` *back to how it was originally in your question*

Comment: I reverted #aform label and this has fixed the problem, your knowledge has helped and the problem is fixed.